# search from apache lucene index and count the result group wise

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am trying to search from lucene index but i want to filter this search . there are two fields contents and and category .suppose i want to search  in files which have "sports" and i also want to count to count how much files are in a and b category . I am trying to achive this with following code . But problem is that if there are millions of the records then it goes slow due to loop execution, suggest me another way to achieve the task.

try {         File indexDir= new File("path of the file")

```
           Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);

                IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
                int maxhits=1000000;
                QueryParser parser1 = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "contents",

                  new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));

          Query qu=parser1.parse("sport");

                TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(, maxhits);
                ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;


          len = hits.length;

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"found times"+len);

                 int docId = 0;
                Document d;





 String category="";

int ctr=0,ctr1=0;

for ( i = 0; i<len; i++) {
docId = hits[i].doc;
d = searcher.doc(docId);
category= d.get(("category"));
if(category.equals("a"))
ctr++;
if(category.equals("b"))
ctr1++;


}

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("wprd found in category a times"+ctr);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("wprd found in category b times"+ctr1);
  }

 catch(Exception ex)

 {

  ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just query for each category you are looking for and get `totalHits`.  Better still would be to use a [TotalHitCountCollector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TotalHitCountCollector.html), instead of getting a `TopDocs` instance:

```
Query query = parser1.parser("+sport +category:a")
TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
search.search(query, collector); 
ctr = collector.getTotalHits();
query = parser1.parser("+sport +category:b")
collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
search.search(query, collector); 
ctr1 = collector.getTotalHits();
```